# Is there any widget for password entry?

Tags: android, passwords, field

I was tryin to find any class to define a password field?
How can we do that?
Do we have a class for that or some method to edittext?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

The first (apparently) deprecated, is to set this property on the widget in your layout resource file

```
android:password="true"
```

From code this is equivalent to calling:

```
myEditTextWidget.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

(note that this also gives you the flexibility to supply your own implementation of the `TransformationMethod` interface).

The second mechanism is to set this property:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

again, equivalent to calling:

```
myEditTextWidget.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                              InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 3):

Better to use the *inputType* property, the *password* one is now deprecated.

`<EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:inputType="textPassword"/>`

Comment: Which SDK release deprecated it?  70% of Android devices are still running Android 1.6 or earlier.

Comment: And from code, that's setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD).

Comment: Don't know when 'password' was deprecated, but inputType works at least since Android 1.5.

Comment: thanks for the extra info - I've collated in my answer so it's all in one place.

Answer (score 2):

In the xml layout file try assigning [this property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:password) to your edittext...

```
android:password="true"
```